# How to compare single element to any element in a collection or list

Tags: java, compare, conditional-statements

```
char[] vowels = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'};

String aWord = "any word";

if(aWord.charAt(0) == 'a' || aWord.charAt(0) == 'e' ) {
//As you can see, this will be very messy by the time I get round to the last vowel.
}

if(aWord.charAt(0) == vowels) {
//This is illegal, is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to get at?
}
```

Self-explanatory in the above code. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With array no you don't have a straight method for but with `Collection.contains()` yes.

For example with `Set` :

```
Set<Character> vowels = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'));
//...
if(vowels.contains(aWord.charAt(0)) {
   // ...
}
```